# Shell script : How to cut part of a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have following string

```
â   â³ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
â   â³ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and would like to get the list of id ? How this can be done using sed or something else ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I pasted the contents of your example into a file named `so.txt`.

```
$ cat so.txt | awk '{ print $7 }' | cut -f2 -d"="
9
10
```

Explanation:

1. `cat so.txt` will print the contents of the file to `stdout`.
2. `awk '{ print $7 }'` will print the seventh column, i.e. the one containing `id=n`
3. `cut -f2 -d"="` will cut the output of step #2 using `=` as the delimiter and get the second column (`-f2`)

If you'd rather get `id=` also, then:

```
$ cat so.txt | awk '{ print $7 }' 
id=9
id=10
```

Comment: Thaks this is exactly what I wanted !

Comment: useless use of cat and cut. awk can do all of it.

Comment: @user229426: You mean _unnecessary_ use of cat and cut, not _useless_, don't you?

Comment: This is a great explanation of using `awk` in combination with cut. I tried to get this exact thing for another use case and struggled a lot with awk man pages and awk tutorials. Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain your code!

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to catch the id number and replace the whole line with the number. Something like this should do it (match everything up to "id=", then match any number of digits, then match the rest of the line):

```
sed -e 's/.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

Do this for every line and you get the list of ids.

Comment: this method gives 9 and 1 but it should be 9 and 10

Comment: Right, I've made a mistake when pasting the sed line. Updated it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A perl-solution:

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /id=(\d+)/' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have `awk` do it all without using `cut`:

```
awk '{print substr($7,index($7,"=")+1)}' inputfile
```

You could use `split()` instead of `substr(index())`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/id=(\d+)/)' file
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input of

```
{Anything}id={ID}{space}{Anything} 
{Anything}id={ID}{space}{Anything}
```

--

```
#! /bin/sh
while read s; do
   rhs=${s##*id=}
   id=${rhs%% *}
   echo $id # Do what you will with $id here
done <so.txt
```

Or if it's always the 7th field

```
#! /bin/sh
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 rest
do
echo ${f7##id=}
done <so.txt
```

**See Also**

[Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)